# How can I create a gradient outlined Text?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a fancy header, with text that is outlined with gradient colors.

Here is my code I tried, but it still doesn't work:

````
:root {
    --blue-purp-gradient: linear-gradient(45deg, #ea00ff, #1900ff);
  } /* This is my varibble */ 

h1 {
    font-size: 52px;
    /* background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #ea00ff, #1900ff); */
    background-size: 200%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--blue-purp-gradient);
}```
````

Comment: If you read the documentation, for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value the color has to be a color not an image (a linear-gradient is like an image, not a color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If transparency is not required, you can try like below:

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #fff; /* same as background */
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ea00ff, #1900ff); 
    background-size: 200%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px #0000;

    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some Text</h1>
```